# How does the new Salesforce Lightning experience for desktop affect sidebar components?

Tags: lightning, sidebar

Maybe there isn't much info yet since this is pretty new but I can't find any info on how sidebar components are going to be affected by the new "lightning experience" UI for the desktop. The screenshots I've seen seem to have done away with a sidebar completely.

[image]

Searching for answers has mostly lead to articles about lightning and Salesforce1, which don't seem relevant.

Comment: Today, there were 4 new Trailhead modules released today as part of a new [Admin Trail - Migrating To Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/trail/lex_admin_migration) path. Perhaps you'll find the answers you seek in one of those modules. I've not gone through them yet to say.

Answer (score 1):

There's now a "Classic Salesforce" and a "Lightning Salesforce". You won't see the current sidebar in the new Lightning Salesforce UI. Instead, you'll see a SF1 mobile-like menu that's on the left as there are no tabs in the Lightning Salesforce UI.